# How to display path in new line after displaying output in Visual Studio code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

[image: Here]

The output that is displayed and the path of folder has no gap (the output javed and path PS... Both are attached. I want to display output "Maha Javed" to appear at one line and then PS.... To display on new line), how can I make the path to display on new line in terminal powershell in visual studio code?

Comment: the output javed and path PS... Both are attached. I want to display output "Maha Javed" to appear at one line and then PS.... To display on new line

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your prompt may be broken, the `Prompt` function is used in Powershell to generate the prompt.

In my case running this in VSC yeilds:

```
( Get-Command Prompt).ScriptBlock

"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml
```

Now as the other commentors have noted this behaviour is not usual. But if your prompt script is different from the above for some reason you can reset it or at least see what it is and indeed change it to what you please.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7 for a full explanation of this.

Comment: I checked by running `( Get- Command Prompt).ScriptBlock ` and it is showing exactly the same output

Answer (score 0):

( Get-Command Prompt).ScriptBlock

same problem what to do in ubuntu 20
How to display path in new line after displaying output in vs code in linux distro

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).